# Create the dockerfile for dash app within Flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask

I add a dash app within a flask app. while it works great when executing 
`python dashapp.py`, it gets complicated when I try to dockerised the whole.

The architecture of the app is the following one :

```
├── project    
│   ├── app     
│   │   ├── __init__.py    
│   │   ├── views.py    
│   │   ├── extensions.py   
│   │   ├── static    
│   │   ├── templates  
│   │   ├── dashapp1    
│   │   │   ├── callback.py   
│   │   │   └── layout.py   
│   │   └── ...   
│   ├── dashapp.py   
│   ├── requirements.txt   
│   ├── .env   
│   └── Dockerfile
```

And here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

ENV FLASK_APP=dashapp
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

COPY . /dashapp

WORKDIR /dashapp
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["dashapp.py"]
```

The registration of the dash app is one in the **init**.py file:

```
def create_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    server.config.from_object(BaseConfig)

    from app.dashapp1.layout import layout as layout1
    from app.dashapp1.callbacks import register_callbacks as register_callbacks1
    register_dashapp(server, 'Dashapp 1', 'dashboard', layout1, register_callbacks1)

    register_extensions(server)
    register_blueprints(server)

    return server
```

I then build and run the app:

```
docker build -t name_app .
docker run -p 5000:5000 name_ap
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dashapp.py", line 6, in <module>
    myapp = create_app()
  File "/app/__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    from dashapp1.layout import layout as layout1
ImportError: No module named dashapp1.layout
```

It's been few days since I can't figure out how to set up the Dockerfile to avoid that issue, therefore any help would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **init**.py file in dashapp1 it will solve your issue

```
├── project    
│   ├── app     
│   │   ├── __init__.py    
│   │   ├── views.py    
│   │   ├── extensions.py   
│   │   ├── static    
│   │   ├── templates  
│   │   ├── dashapp1    
│   │   |   |__init__.py    
│   │   │   ├── callback.py   
│   │   │   └── layout.py   
│   │   └── ...   
│   ├── dashapp.py   
│   ├── requirements.txt   
│   ├── .env   
│   └── Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

thry folowing:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

ENV FLASK_APP=dashapp
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

COPY . /dashapp

WORKDIR /dashapp
VOLUME /dashapp   # <-- Add this
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000       # <-- Add this
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["dashapp.py"]
```

Command to run container

```
docker run \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  -v "/host/path/to/the/project:/dashapp" \ # <-- Add this
  name_ap
```